# Why is dereferencing a pointer called dereferencing?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, terminology, dereference

Why is dereferencing called dereferencing?

I'm just learning pointers properly, and I'd like to know why dereferencing is called that. It confused me as it sounds like you are removing a reference, rather than going via the pointer to the destination.

Can anyone explain why it is called this?

To me something like destination or pointed_to_value would make more sense.

Comment: Destination and pointed-to value are nouns... you're asking about the verb in the title. :-)

Comment: I agree - it's never made any sense to me either why it's called that. I would prefer it if it were called 'following' or somesuch.

Comment: I think your refering to the right direciton I was looking for. Is the word dereferencing a purely CS term? Without using that word in my life aside from this, I tried to assume what it ment, which is where I went wrong I think! Is it a word only used for this situation? Are there other examples where you would use this term?

Comment: Just to confuse matters, the Windows kernel uses "dereference" to mean "decrement reference count": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff557724%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: @PlatinumAzure `getting` still feels more appropriate to me

Answer (score 44, accepted):

A pointer *refers* to an object.  Ergo, we *dereference* the pointer (or, get the referent of the pointer) to get the object pointed-to.

The *de-* prefix most likely comes from the Latin preposition meaning *from*; I suppose you could think of *dereference* as meaning "to obtain the referent (or object) *from the reference*."

Comment: Can you give any other example of the word being used outside of CS?

Comment: @optician:  No; I think it's just technical jargon.

Comment: Perfect, that section about the Latin bit was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you.

Comment: I know it's late for this but "delimit" means to indicate the limit or boundary, rather than to take away limits; other examples include "denote," "demarcate," "delineate," etc.

Answer (score 12):

Dereferencing means taking away the reference and giving you what it was actually referring to.

A pointer to `something` really means that your pointer variable holds a memory address of `something`.  But the pointer can also be thought of as a reference to `something` instead.

Comment: Is it a purely cs term, or can you think of another situation where you would use the same word?

Comment: There's thousands of CS terms that aren't used in "the real world"

Comment: It sounded like it did some to do with making a pointer null, rather than finding something at the end of it. I think I thought that because I thought it sounded like a word that could exist in the real world.

Answer (score 3):

Wiktionary only contains definitions related to programming: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dereference

So it looks like it's really just technical jargon.